# Adding an applet in a submodule to a WAR file in Maven

Tags: java, maven-2, applet, war

I've got a Maven2 project with two submodules, laid out like this:

```
parentproject
|---war-file-project
|---applet-project
```

The POMs in each of them have the appropriate parent-module relationships. The `applet-project` contains a simple applet and is set up with JAR packaging. The `war-file-project` contains a simple WAR file project and is set up with WAR packaging.

When I build, I'd like to make sure that the WAR file contains the resulting JAR file from the `applet-project` in the `/applets` directory.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To achieve that you can simply use the maven-dependency-plugin to copy the dependency to an appropriate location.

Created a [complete example](https://github.com/khmarbaise/war-with-supplemental-artifacts) which you can use as a template.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks khmarbaise for an excellent template!

I've also found one might want to adjust it with the following changes:

- add `<scope>provided</scope>` to the 'supplemental' dependency in war/pom.xml - then supplemental.jar will not be duplicated at /WEB-INF/lib
- add `<stripVersion>true</stripVersion>` to the example maven-dependency-plugin configuration - then applet will be in 'supplemental.jar' instead of something like 'supplemenal-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'
- change `${project.artifactId}-${project.version}` in `<outputDirectory>` to a more reliable `${project.build.finalName}`

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a dependency in the war-project to your applet-project.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
  <artifactId>applet-project</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That will appear to put the JAR file for my applet in WEB-INF/lib, which is not what I want. I'd like it in the root of the WAR file so that it can be downloaded by the user and run in his browser.